# Scrapy only scrapes first 4 starting urls

Tags: scrapy

Here is my spider

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider"
    start_urls = []
    with open("clause/clauses.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            start_urls(line)
    base_url = "<url>"
    start_urls = [base_url + "-".join(url.split()) for url in start_url]

    def start_requests(self):
        self.log("start_urls - {}".format(self.start_urls))
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, dont_filter=True, priority=2, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        text_items = response.css("some css").extract()

        for text in text_items:
            if text == "\n":
                continue
            yield Item({"text" : text})

        yield response.follow(response.css("a::attr(href)").extract_first(), callback=self.parse)
```

There are 20 start urls, yet Im noticing that only the first 4 urls are actually being called and the rest aren't ever executed. The ideal behavior would be for scrappy to first call all 20 start urls, and then from each continue to the next.

Comment: Is there an exception message in your console? Could you provide your clauses.txt file?

Comment: @XetRAFHan there are no exception messages. The clause file has a list of words and those are appended to the base url, going to the site works, its just that after the first 4 requests its not processing the other initial requests.

Comment: what is output of `self.log("start_urls - {}".format(self.start_urls))` do you see all 2 URLs?

Comment: @Umair Nope, I only see the first couple rather than all of the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo:

```
 start_urls = [base_url + "-".join(url.split()) for url in start_url]
```

should probably be:

```
 start_urls = [base_url + "-".join(url.split()) for url in start_urls]
```

Notice the missing `s` in `start_urls`.

And I suspect this:

```
with open("clause/clauses.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        start_urls(line)
```

should be:

```
with open("clause/clauses.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        start_urls.append(line)
```